# Issue loading extension in postres after Homebrew MacOS install

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, timescaledb

I recently installed Postgres 11.3 using Homebrew on MacOSX Mojave.  I'd like to extend a database using TimescaleDB, also installed with Homebrew, but get the following error:

```
tutorial=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/Library/PostgreSQL/11/share/postgresql/extension/timescaledb.control": No such file or directory
```

Looks like the command expects Postgres to be installed in /Library, but `brew info postgres` says it is located in `/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.3`.  Is there a way I can modify the path the command uses or change where Postgres is installed?

Comment: You should report this issue to TimescaleDB devs. They might have to modify the [`timescaledb` formula](https://github.com/timescale/homebrew-tap/blob/master/timescaledb.rb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out I had a previous version of postgres which I had not fully uninstalled.

There were a number of postgres processes running in the Activity Monitor even after `brew remove postgres`.  I killed the one with the lowest PID, restart the computer and reinstalled postgres through Homebrew.

I can now extend databases as expected.